# $wpdb-prepare : Do I have to bind a parameter to the table name?

Tags: select, wpdb

I only do a SELECT on a whole table - and the table is defined in a variable:

```
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'members';
```

Do I have to bind a parameter to this variable?

This caused an error:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM %s", $table, ARRAY_A));
```

But if I skip the "%s", this gives an error as well:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table", ARRAY_A));
```

Should I skip "prepare" in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not want to swap out the tablename. If you do, the table name will be wrapped in quotes and it will trigger a SQL error. Try:

```
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'members';
$qry = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM %s", $table); 
var_dump($qry);

$qry = "SELECT * FROM $table";
var_dump($result);
```

The first string is invalid SQL. The second should work provided that you have a table of the correct name.

`prepare()` is meant to operate on user supplied data-- data that could be from questionable sourced with malicious intent. You do not need to swap out data, like your table name, that is not from a questionable source.

What you want is:

```
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'members';
$qry = "SELECT * FROM $table";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($qry, ARRAY_A);
var_dump($result);
```

By the way, your parenthesis are wrong here (even if the rest worked):

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM %s", $table, ARRAY_A));
```

The `ARRAY_A` is an argument to the `prepare` and not to the `get_results`. It should be (though the value swapping is wrong as explained above):

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results(
  $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM %s", $table), 
  ARRAY_A
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a wrong bracket closing, `$wpdb->prepare` only requires the `query string` and `query parameters`. Then, on `get_results` you can define what kind of results do you need, so:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM %s", $table ),
    ARRAY_A
) or die ( $wpdb->last_error );
```

Edit: you can check for `$wpdb` last SQL error by using this updated code

Comment: That code has one parenthesis too many (an extra one at the end). If I remove the last parenthesis from your code, I get no indication of error from my IDE, but there still occurs an SQL error.

Comment: Please check updated answer

Comment: This will not work as @s_ha_dum explained.